# Stop Microsoft Word 2019 from defaulting to English (United States)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2019

The language in Microsoft Word will default to English (United States) for all documents despite setting the default language as English (Australia) and changing the "Normal" style language to English (Australia).

Comment: Have you uninstalled the English language from Office or changed Office to use a different language pack?

Comment: Yes. That didn't work.

Comment: **You submitted an answer to that effect.** Your Office installation is set to use whatever language Windows is configured to use.  Which is the reason your solution worked.

Comment: I had tried options 1-3 before but it didn't fix the problem. Option 4 is only a temporary fix. The problem would resurface on new documents. I didn't test the macro solution.

Comment: See my article on this on the Microsoft site: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b It has macro solutions for more stubborn situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried several fixes and the only method that worked was:

1. Open Windows Search
2. Edit Language and Keyboard options
3. Under preferred languages, click Add a language
4. select English (Australia) and install
5. Click Keyboard at the top
6. Under Override for default input method, select English (Australia)

To keep the same keyboard layout, use English (Europe) instead of English (Australia).

Answer (score 0):

What is you system language set to? Microsoft Word may be defaulting to the system language, rather than the app default. Try changing the System default to your language of choice.